# A custom UITableViewCell is not causing any errors, but it also won't display

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a strange issue with attempting to get my custom table view cell to display. It seems logically correct. It follows the Apple Documentation logic and about every site's exact logic, yet it won't display. Is there something I', missing?

---

```
class FavTableCell: UITableViewCell{
@IBOutlet weak var Testo : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TestoBackgoundImage : UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    // any extra code or logic here
}
```

}

```
           class TableViewClass : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            TableView.delegate = self
            TableView.dataSource = self
            TableView.register(CustomTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Table")

        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return TableArray.count
    }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let TableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Table", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableCell



        TableCell.TestoBackgoundImage?.image = Image Literal// image literal here
        TableCell.Testo?.text = self.TableArray[indexPath.row]


        return TableCell
    }

}
```

Comment: `FavTableCell` or `CustomTableCell`?

Comment: change `TableCell.TestoBackgoundImage?.image` to `TableCell.TestoBackgoundImage.image`  if crashed then below answer is yours

Comment: I meant CustomTableCell

Answer (score 0):

If you have created it as a prototype cell ( design is inside the table itself ) then remove

```
tableView.register(CustomTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Table")
```

if it's an xib then do

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Table")
```

Comment: I attempted the change, but it caused a crash. Is the UINib name meant to refer to the class or the storyboard object?

Comment: Do you have `CustomTableCell.xib` ? or where you create layout of cell ?

Comment: I created my cell in the storyboard that exists inside of the table view as a prototype cell. I created a separate file for the class for the UITableCell, and a separate class for the class containing  the UItableView.

Comment: then comment the line and try